# how to link to ncurses library in the make file

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to link to an external library of C++ ncurses. How I can do this in the make file of ROS? I use Electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69022/how-to-link-to-ncurses-library-in-the-make-file/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

If you want to use ncurses++ (in electric) you should add the following to your CMakeList.txt:

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED )
pkg_check_modules ( ncurses++ REQUIRED ncurses++ )

add_executable ( my_exec path_to_my_exec/my_exec.cpp )
target_link_libraries ( my_exec ${ncurses++_LIBRARIES} )
```

And then modify the manifest.xml of your package to let know ROS that you are using an external library:

```
<rosdep name="ncurses++"/>
```

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2